# Leaflet.timeline plugin not adding to map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using the **[Leaflet.timeline plugin](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.timeline)** in order to show a timeline slider on my LeafletJS map. For some reason I can't get the timeline slider control to appear on my map. I am not getting an error in console, so I am unsure how to proceed. Anyone have any clues as to what is going on?

This is what i am doing:

```
var timeline = L.timeline(campsData);
timeline.addTo(map);
```

I made sure my data object contained the following properties as stated in the documentation for the plugin (example):

```
"start": "2015-06-23"
"end": "2016-02-23"
```

*Note: I have a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/r69otqnc/) link but I can't post http (the timeline plugin in this case), so it's just the code sans plugin. I have demo (non jsfiddle) [here](http://ogmda.com/sandbox/map-slider3.html) with everything needed.*